# Rails scope method returns WhereChain instead of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my `Deal` class, I've added a scope method:

```
scope :current, -> { where {|d| d.end_date > Date.today} }
```

It returns the right data, but rather than returning an array that I can count, iterate, etc, it returns an `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain`, and I can't do anything with that.

I notice that a call to `Deal.current` starts with "`@scope=`":

```
Deal.current                                                                                                                   
  Deal Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "deals".* FROM "deals"
=> #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x00007fbc61228038
 @scope=
  [#<Deal:0x00007fbc5fdb2400
    id: 7,
```

I suppose if I knew how to use a "normal" `where` statement for comparison (rather than equality) such as `where(end_date>Date.today)` that would band-aid my problem, since a scope method using a simple `where` statement like `scope :posted, -> { where.not(posted_date:nil) }` returns a normal useable `ActiveRecord.Relation`, but I do want to figure out how to use more complex where queries like this one correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use as following:

```rb
scope :current, -> { where('end_date > ?', Date.today) }
```

The block-syntax for a `where`-call, does not exist in Rails.

You could also look into `arel` (https://robots.thoughtbot.com/using-arel-to-compose-sql-queries);

```rb
deal = Deal.arel_table
Deal.where(deal[:end_date].gt(Date.today))
```

Comment: Not entirely, no! Using the arel_table, it's still ruby, and not really SQL, but the more advanced queries, the closer to SQL! Can't avoid it forever :).